# ListView header ignores layout_height

Tags: android, listview, layout

I inflate this view, and add it to my ListView as a header. I am trying to make it 500dp high (hard coded, for the sake of this example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/repeat_background"
              android:layout_height="500dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/filter_menu" android:src="@drawable/ic_sort"
               android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:padding="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="0"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:onClick="showPopup"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The ListView does not respect the authoritah of its header and wraps it on its content. Can anyone please explain what happens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key to understand what's going on is figuring out how ListView headers and footers are implemented. They're a trick: the moment you add the first header or footer to your ListView, your ListAdapter is wrapped in a `HeaderViewListAdapter` (happens on [line 270 of ListView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/799812cd6f7f9aa4a87d81dafd273d51ac5ba992/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#L270)). The HeaderListViewAdapter is a list adapter that tweaks `count` and `position` values to include the headers and footers; headers and footers become normal list items that the system manages for you.

If you look at [line 207 of HeaderListViewAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/799812cd6f7f9aa4a87d81dafd273d51ac5ba992/core/java/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java#L207), you'll see that the `getView` implementation ignores the `parent` view when adding a header or footer. This has the effect that its `mLayoutParams` doesn't get initialized from XML (can't really point you to the source code, just something I've found out over time).

If you then follow the calls to `getView` for a bit, past [line 2237 of AbsListView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/799812cd6f7f9aa4a87d81dafd273d51ac5ba992/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L2237), and follow the calls for `obtainView` for a bit and search for `LayoutParams` (which is what I just did) you end up at [line 1182 of ListView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/799812cd6f7f9aa4a87d81dafd273d51ac5ba992/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#L1182). Here you see that, if the layout params are `null` when the child view is measured, it calls out to `generateDefaultLayoutParams()`, which is implemented on [line 6065 of AbsListView.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/799812cd6f7f9aa4a87d81dafd273d51ac5ba992/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java#L6065):

```
@Override
protected ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
}
```

...and that's where your `WRAP_CONTENT` is coming from.

As an easy work-around, just wrap the `<LinearLayout/>` of your XML inside a `<FrameLayout/>`. Keep the 500dp on the LinearLayout and make the FrameLayout have a layout height of WRAP_CONTENT (which will get ignored anyway).

Comment: +1 for elaborate answer. I am not sure what to think of this; bug - or feature? The abstraction, or the mental model breaks down when things do not work as expected.